# .htaccess files keeps redirecting in firefox

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, caching

I modified my .htaccess file to prevent hotlinking. After that I reversed the change. Now in firefox it is still redirecting from domainname.com/imagedir/image1.jpg to domainname.com when I enter the URL directly. In other browsers it is working fine.

Comment: Clear the cache of the browser.

Comment: It didn't work. I cleared the cache and did `crtl+f5` to reload the page still same issue.